# How to use Get-WinEvent to get all information between a specific time period?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, logging, events

### Some background

I am encountering some crash and freeze issues I want to get a better handle on. For this, I want to investigate all available event & log information for a specific time period.

I have a very good handle on *when* something bad happened, but not *why*.
So, f.e. I would like to pull all potentially relevant information from a specific day between a specific 15min period, say "26-11-2021 15:00" to "26-11-2021 15:15".

If found it hard to use the inbuilt windows event-viewer to give me access to this information, as I couldn't figure out how to get information across *all* log-files to show up in a compact way.
[image]

Then I learnt about [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) (started as admin) and the [Get-WinEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.2) tool. However, I'm lost in the documentation and couldn't achieve my primary goal:

#### How can I create a 'filtered' text-file of all (relevant) log-entries from a specific time-period?

After quite some time of internet-browsing, I found a *partial* solution to my problem, copy-pasting some one-liner I found:
[image]

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | % {Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName=$_.LogName;StartTime="26-11-2021 15:00";EndTime="26-11-2021 15:15"; Level=(1,2,3) } -ea 0} | sort timecreated -des >> C:\temp\events.txt
```

This is helpful, but without understanding the syntax much, I've noticed two shortcomings:

- The output log entries are sometimes truncated, f.e.:
  [image]
- I don't seem to catch really *all* entries. In particular, I *know* that in a specific period a system-restart occurred and would show up in the Event Viewer as critical/error event:
  [image: List item]
  But I can't find that in the generated text-output for the same period of time.

So this led me to believe, that I still don't have found the best way to get what I want.
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: It might be simpler to use [Get-EventLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) using the parameters of `-After` and  `-Before`. For a very complete script see [this article](https://adamtheautomator.com/get-eventlog/).

Comment: Both `StartTime` and `EndTime` should be `DateTime` objects. You are giving it strings, but these may or may not be converted to DateTime objects correctly, depending on your systems culture/locale. Try with real DateTime objects like `$start = Get-Date -Year 2021 -Month 11 -Day 26 -Hour 15 -Minute 0 -Second 0` or `$start = [datetime]::ParseExact('26-11-2021 15:00', 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm', $null)`

Comment: @Theo thanks for this comment. I *did* get the correctly clipped output in my exported files, it just that I a) don't get the full description text, b) don't seem to get all events (no shutdown/restart)